# Active Directory Group Policy

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I have Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition SP2 64 bit and I have OU groups to apply policies like WSUS, deploying programs, etc. I had updated of administrative tools pack so I decide to install Windows Server 2003 R2 Administration Tools Pack (x64) after the installation I had problem when I tried to open policies from Active Directory Users and Computers right-click on OU then group policy try to edit on of the policies there is an

**error message** said

> windows can not find 'gpedit.msc'.
>   Make sure you typed the name
>   correctly, and then try again. to
>   search for a file, click the start
>   button, and click Search.

***Another message said:***

> Failed to start the Group policy
>   snapin. The gpedit.msc file may be
>   missing, files with .msc extension mau
>   not be associated with mmc.exe, or you
>   may not have the appropriate rights.
>
> ***Details:***
>
> The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: The error messages are very specific. What do you not understand about them? Have you checked to see if gpedit.msc is even on the computer? If it is it may simply be in the wrong location. Have you check the other things mentioned in the second message?

Answer (score 4):

Try installing the Microsoft Group Policy Management Console (GPMC) - it's far better than the built-in AD editor and provides such things as GP diagnostics and profiling:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0a6d4c24-8cbd-4b35-9272-dd3cbfc81887